# How to consider date in a Linq-to-Entities query?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I check records with specific `Id` in a SQL Server database table using Linq-to-Entities (I use Entity Framework 6) whether at least one of the record has column named `IsNormal` has `false` value.

Here is my Linq-to-Entities query:

```
bool IsServiceable = Context.InspectionReviews.Any(i => i.ObjectId == x.Id  && i.IsNormal == false);
```

And here is screenshot of the database table that I query:

[image]

I need to change query above as I would like to consider the current date, `month` and `year`. In other words, I need to alter the query in such a way that it will check rows in database only for current `year` and `month`.

How do I change the query above to make changes that I described above?

Comment: Datetime datetoday = DateTime.Now;
bool IsServiceable = Context.InspectionReviews.Any(i => i.ObjectId == x.Id  && !i.IsNormal && i.DateRiew.Year == datetoday .Year && i.DateRiew.Month == datetoday .Month)

Comment: Can I use it like this:

Comment: bool IsServiceable = Context.InspectionReviews.Any(i => i.ObjectId == x.Id && !i.IsNormal && i.DateRiew.Year == DateTime.Year && i.DateRiew.Month == DateTime.Month)

Comment: @J4ime why do I have to create Datetime variable?I can create it inside query

Comment: DateTime.Month no, DateTime.Now.Month is today.